# How do I extract just the addresses/locations from this data set and put them in column B and C in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

My data set looks like this and it's all in Column A going straight down with no deviation from this formatting:

```
Let's Pretend Parties
317 Jenkins St
Grapevine TX 76051 USA
Let's Pretend Parties
3000 Grapevine Mills Pkwy
Grapevine TX 76051 USA
Tip Toes Holland
60 E. 8th St
Holland MI 49423 USA
Tugboat and The Bird
318 Park Avenue North
Winter Park FL 32789 USA
Overall Fun
3429 West 7th St
Fort Worth TX 76107 USA
Bad Kitty Kids
255 96th St
Stone Harbor NJ 8247 USA
```

Is it possible to move the the address into column B?  Is it possible to move the locations into Column C?

i.e.

```
Column A:                  Column B:                     Column C: 
Let's Pretend Parties      317 Jenkins St                Grapevine TX 76051 USA
Let's Pretend Parties      3000 Grapevine Mills Pkwy     Grapevine TX 76051 USA
```

Or, if this isn't possible, to just move them to each of their own columns but lined up and I can manually delete blank spaces?

I'm totally at a loss on this as I'm a Google Sheets newbie.
Thanks!

I'm a complete noob to Google Sheets.  I already tried googling solutions and tried using a query with skipping--but I couldn't get it to neatly line up and it kept doubling/tripling stuff from Column A.

Appreciate anyone who answers.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

```
=ArrayFormula(XLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(A:A)/3),3),SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A:A)),FILTER(A:A,A:A<>""),))
```

Comment: Wanted to personally thank you as well, ztiaa.  Had another troublesome sheet and the first query skipping solution didn't work.  This one worked perfectly.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(A1:A10; "skipping 3"; )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
={QUERY(A:A, "SKIPPING 3"),QUERY({"";"";A:A},"SKIPPING 3 OFFSET 1"),QUERY({"";A:A},"SKIPPING 3 OFFSET 1")}
```

- 

[image]

Comment: Unbelievable.  It works.  Thank you so much!  Everyone here is the best :)